# Getting data from web service from android

Tags: android, web-services, bufferedreader

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(new URI(address));
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

When I retrieve information like that, bufferedreader in contains only one long line with the whole text. It doesn't divide break data into lines. As a result, only first 3 kwords are fit into the line and the rest is losed. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
URL url = new URI(address).toURL();
InputStream is = url.openStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this?

```
String data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```